# while trying web rshiny applicartion :3838/myapp

Tags: r, shiny

while i am trying to hit the webpage with :3838/myapp I am getting the below error is getting generated in the logs

```
Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
  69: ui
   3: <Anonymous>
   1: rmarkdown::run
Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
  69: ui
   3: <Anonymous>
   1: rmarkdown::run
```

any one know what changes should be made in config file?

Comment: Please provide us with a [reproducible example](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#getting-help).

Comment: i deployed the application in aws linux machine.we have installed rstudio,rbase,shiny server in the machine.
the app is running fine from the rstudio.
the application should be available to end users when they hit the link :3838/myapps.but it is showing the above error in logs file